# How to add type hints for an inner or nested function inside the stub file

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to add type hints for an inner function (or nested function) inside the stub file?

code in parsable_base.py

```
class TemplateBase:
    def copy(self, _parent=None):
        def walk_properties(template_based):
            for prop_holder in template_based.properties.values():
                if isinstance(prop_holder.prop, TemplateBase):
                    walk_properties(prop_holder.prop)
                elif isinstance(prop_value, PrimitiveBase):
                    value_copies[prop_value] = prop_value.copy()
                else:
                    references.append(prop_value)

        value_copies = {}
        references = []
        walk_properties(self)
```

code in parsable_base.pyi

```
class TemplateBase(ParsableBase):
    def copy(self: _T, _parent=...) -> _T: ...
```

I would like to add a type hint (`TemplateBase`) for argument `template_based`  in the inner function `walk_properties`.

I know I can add it in the code file (parsable_base.py) like:

```
        def walk_properties(template_based: TemplateBase) -> None:
```

But I would like to keep my code file clean and add it in the stub file (parsable_base.pyi).
I would think it would be something like:

```
class TemplateBase(ParsableBase):
    def copy(self: _T, _parent=...) -> _T:
        def walk_properties(template_based: TemplateBase) -> None: ...
```

But my IDE (PyCharm) doesn't recognise it so I think it's wrong.

How do I do it properly.

parsable_base.py and parsable_base.pyi are in the same folder (package).

Comment: If this is your own code better to add the annotations in the file itself, rather than separate stub file.  If you are making stubs for a 3rd party package then the inner function isn't a visible part of the interface so I doubt it is possible to type it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested function is not a part of the API as it's inaccessible (for example trying to typehint a random variable under a function would act the same), so a stub file can't document it.

If the library is your own, I'd recommend simply doing typing in the Python file

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a minimal version of the issue you are facing:

```py
class A:
    def func(self, var: A) -> None:
        ...
```

Which produces:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\72658624.py", line 2, in <module>
    class A:
  File "...\72658624.py", line 3, in A
    def func(self, var: A) -> None:
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

---

This issue can be solved by importing `annotations` from `__future__`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class A:
    def func(self, var: A) -> None:
        ...
```

Now it compiles properly. See [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) for more information. In short, this allows type hints for names that have not been defined yet. As you can guess, when Python parses the file, the class `A` has not been fully defined yet when it encounters `var: A`, causing the issue.

Comment: `__future__` was a Python 2 thing, is that still relevant with Python 3? (I know it still works, that was the whole point, but I'm pretty sure it's not needed.)

Comment: I'm quite certain that it is still in use. For example, the `annotations` functionality was placed in `__future__` in 2017 for Python 3.7. Just like then, it refers to (potential) future functionality. In this example, it is needed in order for the program (Which I ran in Python 3.10) to compile.

Comment: OK, I was not aware that future was still relevant, but I guess it continues to make sense as new features are added all the time. Thanks for the clarification!